# Is there any reason to use JavaScript library plugins in grails that expose the given library via TagLibs instead of just using it directly?

Tags: javascript, grails, taglib

If you search the grails plugin site, you'll find lots of plugins for JQuery and other JavaScript libraries.  Most of these expose the given JavaScript library functionality through Grails TagLibs.  Is this really an advantage, and if so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to use the JavaScript taglibs over plain JavaScript. For example, if you want to create a link that submits an AJAX request and updates a DIV with the response I find it easier to write

```
<g:remoteLink action="show" id="1" update="myDiv" 
        onLoading="showSpinner();">Click Me</g:remoteLink>
```

than the corresponding JavaScript.

If you have the JQuery plugin installed and decide you want to replace JQuery with Prototype (for example), the tags above should continue to work once you've replaced the JQuery plugin with the Prototype plugin. This would not be possible if you just copied the .js files into `web-app/js` (instead of using the plugins).

Ultimately, if you use the JS plugins, you application "knows" which JS libraries are using. Other plugins (e.g. [resources](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/)) can then use this information to your advantage.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using the grails remote tags can be beneficial, as you pointed out.  However, most 3rd party taglibs aren't written this way.

Comment: After trying both methods, I am accepting your answer.  I find using the plugin with tags such as remoteLink allows for cleaner code and less potential to introduce your own JavaScript bugs

Answer (score 7):

To answer your actual question as to whether using TagLibs to expose the JavaScript functionality is an advantage, my answer would be generally no.  But you're likely to get just as many people disagree with me as those that would agree.  Especially folks that have spent time creating these TagLibs.

I just find it much easier to deal with the JavaScript directly than to go through a taglib.  The only exceptions I might consider are the grails given remote taglibs but I still don't use them, personally.

Comment: Personally I find them a little misleading sometimes especially if you don't use the remote taglibs. Also at times you find these plugins on the portal and you think they have got some sort of extra features, but you find out that all they do is include the javascript tags for you which I find useless.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is just an extension onto the javascript library.  It offers *no new* features that Javascript doesn't offer itself.  It does, however, make your life **a lot** easier when doing things such as (but not limited to)

- Dom Manipulation
- Tree Traversal
- Ajax
- And much more

It is not necessary when you are just doing something simple and small here or there. But more often than not, when you are doing a big project, it makes sense to include jQuery (31 KB and 1 HTTP request) and use it to your advantage.

Comment: This didn't seem to answer the question. I think Pete was asking about the advantages of including jQuery using a Grails tag versus using a plain old script tag.

Comment: Ahh, I believe you're right.  I thought he was asking something else do to the title of the question.